# Difference in length of lines computed with GeoPandas or in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, geopandas

So, first of all, here is a test file: https://we.tl/t-xqo5KyRlqD

The column length was added using QGIS (v 3.10 A Coruña), field calculator and adding parameter $length.

If the file is opened with geopandas (v 0.6.1), the property length outputs this:

`a.length
Out[8]: 
0    1581.729679
1     899.177689
2      38.054220
3      47.333848
4     189.591771
5     275.946388
dtype: float64`

the values obtained by qgis are:

`a['length']
Out[9]: 
0    1580.830737
1     898.686067
2      38.033291
3      47.307854
4     189.489982
5     275.796306
Name: length, dtype: float64`

As you can see there is a difference of a few centimeters.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes both are correct. The difference is because one it taking into account the curvature of the earth while the other is not.

See following images:[image]

and [image]

Comment: I know the difference between one an another, I did not think that QGIS was providing elipsoidal and GeoPandas cartesian. Thank you!